# Playing tween animation in android

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm fairly new to programming and have a question in mind. I want to make an animation effect in which a horizontal bar moves from the top of the screen to the bottom of the screen and than from the bottom to the top with a specific speed. Now currently, I'm using frame animation in which series of images are played which give an effect as if the bar is moving from the top to bottom.

Now what my question is how can I achieve it through tween animation as it will use just one image for this effect to work as I want.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Animation` function for it. Create a new folder for it in `resource` folder to save all types of animation `xml` classes.

For slide in bottom animation, use this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="100%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

For slide in top animation, use this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:toYDelta="0%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

For slide out bottom animation, use this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="0" 
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

For slide out top animation, use this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:toYDelta="100%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

And in your Activity, initialize `Animation` globally first like:

```
    Animation anim;
```

And get id of the type of animation you want inside `onCreate` like:

```
anim = (Animation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Play.this,
            R.anim.slide_in_bottom);
```

And then set your animation when you need to call it like :

```
container.setAnimation(anim);
anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
                    MyTask();
                    container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
container.startAnimation(anim);
```

Here `container` is the parent layout i.e. `LinearLayout` of your main `xml` class.

Comment: Bro only if you could edit the answer with Image view implementation lol

Comment: I've given you sample code of it. Now try to increase your skills by hit and try methods. Get errors then check logcat and try to understand it.

Comment: Got it right through another code, but i am using your xml file. The speed of animation is very fast. Can i slow it down a bit more. P.S i know you are already using longAnimTime

Comment: When animation starts, use `anim.setDuration(2000);`

Comment: You can change time according to you.