# Play sound while animating imageview and should stop when imageview animation is stopped

Tags: android, android-animation

Is there any solution that I can play sound while my `imageView` is animating. 
I've tried this:

```
public void bounceInterpolar(View thumbnailView){
  ImageView animatedImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_animation);

 Animation animation 
   = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animation);
  animatedImage.startAnimation(animation);

  mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soho);
  animatedImage = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.img_animation);

  animatedImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         mp.start();
     }
 });
```

Issue: By clicking on `imageView`, once the animation is over and then if I click on the `imageView` 2nd time, then the sound is played which is not my requirement. Need to play the sound parallel along with animation.

Comment: For it you should start animation like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29406261/4404791

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please set animation listener to your animation object

```
     animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
            {
                if (m_player != null && m_player.isPlaying())
                {
                    m_player.stop();
                    m_player.release();
                    m_player = null;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: @ user2809692 - thanks. You can accept answers it it works for you

Comment: @ Android Weblineindia - Your answer did not add much to my answer that I posted first except error checking.  
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/which-answer-do-i-accept-if-i-have-multiple-correct-answers

Answer (score 0):

You need to add listener to the animation.

```
animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                 mp.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                mp.stop();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
```